# Cannot get text from JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, gettext, jtextpane

So I have a `JTextPane`, and I have a method that returns a `String` containing the text in the `JTextPane`. I have been trying to fix this for weeks. The `getText()` method returns a blank line. I tried getting the document length, but that returns 0.

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CodeTabs extends JTabbedPane {
    private JTextPane codearea;
    private JScrollPane scroll;

    public CodeTabs() {
        setTabPlacement(JTabbedPane.BOTTOM);

        codearea = new JTextPane();

        scroll = new JScrollPane(codearea, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));

        addTab("Code", scroll);
    }

    public String getCode() {
        String s = codearea.getText();

        System.out.println(s);

        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Might sound stupid but do call `setText()` or type in text before attempting to `getText()`. It also might help providing a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) as I cant see anything wrong with the code from the given class, must be something else. BTW should not really extend `JTabbedPane` without good reason simply create an instance of it and add to the instance IMO

Comment: I tried that too, setText works, and if I use the getText method, it gets the text I set manually. But if I set the text in the program then add text in the program, it only returns the text I set in the program.

Comment: Is your GUI being created on [`Event Dispatch Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)? And how do you call the `getCode()` in your interface after typing in text via button? An sscce would help for better help sooner

Comment: I hate to sound noobish, but what is that?

Comment: I call the getCode() from another JTabbedPane class.

Comment: Basically take a read on the link. But you must wrap creation and manipulation of Swing components in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {@Override public void run() {//code to create ui goes here }});` block.

Comment: I am really confused now... where do I put the code you just wrote? And what is a UI? (It sounds familiar...)

Comment: See my answer. That shows where that code could go. UI = User interface

Answer (score 2):

I took your code and added a main method and a button to trigger the `getCode()` method. Everything works as expected. When I type something in the text area, it gets printed when I press the button.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CodeTabs extends JTabbedPane {
  private JTextPane codearea;
  private JScrollPane scroll;

  public CodeTabs() {
    setTabPlacement(JTabbedPane.BOTTOM);

    codearea = new JTextPane();

    scroll = new JScrollPane(codearea, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(  300,300 ));

    JPanel panel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
    panel.add( scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER );
    JButton comp = new JButton( "Print text" );
    comp.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
        getCode();
      }
    } );
    panel.add( comp, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

    addTab( "Code", panel );
  }

  public String getCode() {
    String s = codearea.getText();

    System.out.println(s);

    return s;
  }

  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame( "TestFrame" );
        frame.getContentPane().add( new CodeTabs() );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
      }
    } );
  }
}
```

Note: there is no need to extend `JTabbedPane`. Use it instead of extending it (I left it in the code posted in this answer to match your code as closely as possible)

Comment: How do I do this if I have a class that extends JFrame?

Comment: @user1845954 1) there is no need to have a class that extends `JFrame` 2) whether or not your class extends `JFrame` seems irrelevant for this problem. If you have an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) illustrating your problem, add it to your question and we can take a look at it

Comment: Should I just have one class for my whole program then?

Comment: @user1845954 Of course not. I meant you do not need to extend `JFrame` but rather use one

Comment: Then what component should I extend?

Answer (score 0):

Do this way:-

```
codearea.getDocument().getText(0, codearea.getDocument().getLength());
```

Comment: That was one of the many things I tried, it gives me an error that says "unreported exception BadLocationException; must be caught or declared to be thrown". So I put the try statement in there, and still gives me nothing.